# GSAP + three js

Tags: three.js, transition, gsap

I was trying to get smooth effect while rotating or increasing in size a figure.

```
  welcomeWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    cube.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    TweenMax.to(cube.scale, 1, { ease: Power4.easeInOut });
  });

//or 

  welcomeWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    TweenLite.to(cube.scale, 1, {
      css: {
        x: e.movementX,
        y: e.movementY,
        z: e.movementX
      }
    });

    cube.rotation.x += e.movementX / 250;
    cube.rotation.y += e.movementY / 250;
    cube.rotation.z += e.movementX / 250;
  });
//tried this but it won't work
        controls.enableDamping = true;
        controls.minPolarAngle = 0.8;
        controls.maxPolarAngle = 2.4;
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.07;
        controls.rotateSpeed = 0.07;
```

But every time I get:
Invalid property css set to {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0} Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()

Comment: The warning means that you're loading GSAP 3 but the code you show is GSAP 2's format. We at GreenSock recommend using the [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3) format, but you're free to use the GSAP 2 format as long as you're not using one of the unsupported features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to scale the cube, for example to `(2, 2, 2)`, you'll need to do something like this:

```
TweenMax.to(cube.scale, 1, { x: 2, y: 2, z: 2, ease: Power4.easeInOut });
```

There's no reason to use `css:{}` with a cube, since 3D objects in THREE.js don't follow CSS attributes.